# How to exclude ICollection in .NET 7 class request serialization?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, json-deserialization

Ignore `ICollection` in request from my class

```
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<ArchivoTxtEstado>), 200)]
```

My class `ArchivoTxtEstado` in request show ICollection too - how to ignore it?

```
public partial class ArchivoTxtEstado
{
    public int IdArchivoTxtEstado { get; set; }

    public string? Codigo { get; set; }
    public string? Nombre { get; set; }
    public string? Descripcion { get; set; }

    public DateTime? FechaRegistro { get; set; }

    public bool? Activo { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ArchivoTxtSri> ArchivoTxtSri { get; set; } = new List<ArchivoTxtSri>();
}
```

I want to exclude

```
public virtual ICollection<ArchivoTxtSri> ArchivoTxtSri { get; set; } = new List<ArchivoTxtSri>
```

from my request.

Answer (score 0):

Just simply add a `[JsonIgnore]` annotation on the property you want to exclude from JSON serialization:

```
public partial class ArchivoTxtEstado
{
    public int IdArchivoTxtEstado { get; set; }

    public string? Codigo { get; set; }
    public string? Nombre { get; set; }
    public string? Descripcion { get; set; }

    public DateTime? FechaRegistro { get; set; }

    public bool? Activo { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<ArchivoTxtSri> ArchivoTxtSri { get; set; } = new List<ArchivoTxtSri>();
}
```

See [official MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/ignore-properties?pivots=dotnet-6-0) for more details